# Windows 10 wifi fluctuating signal strength

Tags: networking, windows-10, router

*Current Windows 10 version -  1703 OS Build - 15063.332
HP 15-r*

Wifi signal strength and speed started fluctuating after creator update.
Tried everything(resetting windows, router)

**Signal sensitivity** was the problem, it was on medium(which is default) so i disabled it and the wifi was back to normal.

**The problem is when ever I restart or sleep my laptop the setting stays the same but wifi starts to fluctuate, so i have to change it to low then back to disable, which is really annoying.**

How do I solve that?